# Compare array format

Tags: c#

I have an array which contains different blocks of data and i have to extract the blocks which contain the date and the hour. How could i do that?

```
string[] s={"File", "Block", "Detected:", "2010-08-11", "11:48:50", etc...}
```

The date and time are not always on the same position but they do have the same format

Comment: Can you reformat your code? It doesn't look valid: (1) you are assigning a string to a string array, (2) the nested double quotes do not look right.

Comment: Please describe the problem better, because it's not clear what do you want to get...Just date from that s? Or s that contains the date block? For getting date, if its in same format everywhere, you can use some Regex .. See this http://gsharper.blogspot.com/2007/03/hi-since-i-always-forget-this-one-ill.html to get what i meant.

Comment: Please format your code as such. Also put this into a C# file and let the compiler help you turn this into a line of valid C# code. That will help finding a good answer. (Good question => good answer)

Comment: I am sorry about the mistyped code. I already have the array build. It goes like this:
string[] s={"File", "Block", "Detected:", "2010-08-11", "11:48:50", etc...}
The problem is that the date and time aren't always on the same position. Their format however stays the same every time.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. You can use the "Edit" button below your question to put this information into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you know that the date and the time will be at some position inside the array, you can iterate through the array and look for something that *looks like* a date or a time. Example:

```
foreach (str in s) {
    if (Regex.IsMatch(str, @"\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d")) {
        // found the date
    }
}
```

or, using LINQ:

```
string myDate = (from str in s
                 where Regex.IsMatch(str, @"\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d")
                 select str).First();
```

For identifying the time, you could use the Regex `\d\d:\d\d:\d\d`.

(All code untested, since I don't have Visual Studio available right now.)

Answer (score 0):

```
        string[] sArr = { "File", "Block", "Detected:", "2010-08-11", "11:48:50", "29.01.1987 12:23" };

        foreach (var s in sArr)
        {
            DateTime d;

            if (DateTime.TryParse(s, out d))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(d);
            }
        }
```